# State income taxes

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax

I work for a company based in Georgia but live in Florida and the company told me that they have to start deducting Georgia income tax even if I don't live or work in Georgia. Any way out of this?

Answer (score -1):

Change the number allowances on the state version of the W-4 to a ridiculously high number like 50.

But technically you would want to withhold because you will have to file a non resident tax return in Georgia.

Looking at the instructions for the [Georgia version of the W-4](http://dor.georgia.gov/documents/g-4) you will have an opportunity to in the future claim exempt:

> Line 8:
>
> a) Check the first box if you qualify to claim exempt from
>   withholding. You can claim exempt if you filed a Georgia income tax
>   return last year and the amount on Line 4 of Form 500EZ or Line 16 of
>   Form 500 was zero, and you expect to file a Georgia tax return this
>   year and will not have a tax liability. You can not claim exempt if
>   you did not file a Georgia income tax return for the previous tax
>   year. **Receiving a refund in the previous tax year does not qualify you
>   to claim exempt.**

Comment: withholding or dependents?

Comment: Technically, he talking "allowances."